# starting/stopping service in /etc/init.d/ with fork and execvp does not work

Tags: c, linux, fork, execvp

I developed the following function inorder to execute shell command from my C code

```
int mycmd(char *cmd, int n, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    int i, pid;
    static int mycmd_pfds[2];

    char *argv[n+2];
    argv[0] = cmd;

    va_start(arg,n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        argv[i+1] = va_arg(arg, char*);
    }
    va_end(arg);
    argv[n+1] = NULL;


    if (pipe(mycmd_pfds) < 0)
        return -1;

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        return -1;

    if (pid == 0) {
        /* child */
        close(mycmd_pfds[0]);
        dup2(mycmd_pfds[1], 1);
        close(mycmd_pfds[1]);

        execvp(argv[0], (char **) argv);
        exit(ESRCH);
    } else if (pid < 0)
        return -1;

    /* parent */
    close(mycmd_pfds[1]);

    int status;
    while (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != pid);

    close(mycmd_pfds[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

This function works fine with linux commands like `ls`. But when I start a service with this function it does not work and then the service is not started.

I tried

```
mycmd("/etc/init.d/sysntpd", 1, "start");
```

I tried also

```
mycmd("/bin/sh", 2, "/etc/init.d/sysntpd", "start");
```

and both do not work. I added echo at the beginning of the script I can see the (with `read` of the pipe) that the echo message is displayed but the service is not started.

What I m missing? how can I make the service started from my C code? (I should call only `/etc/init.d/sysntpd`).

Comment: Why is it a good idea to do it from your code rather than having the system do it automatically?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In fact I' m developing a data model with C code. in which the user can ask my application to start or stop a desired service.

Comment: You could improve the error reporting if the `execvp()` fails: print `errno` or `strerror(errno)` to standard error.  Are you getting permission problems?  Are you running your service as root?  What is the pipe for?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I m running my c function as root.

Comment: Does the service script you're trying to run have `#!...` at the start?  Are the executable bits set on the script?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The pipe is because I m using the function for other purposes in order to read othe commands output

Comment: @AndrewHenle. the script file start with `#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common`

Comment: That's a single shebang line? Do any of the other commands in `/etc/init.d` contain that, because I've not seen that used and I'm a little dubious about what it does.

Comment: My concern about the pipe is … well, you've connected the standard output of the service to the pipe, but you're never reading from it, so if the service does write much to standard output, you're going to block it, and it will never terminate because you're waiting for it to terminate and it is waiting for you to read what it said.  However, commands that are appropriate for running from `/etc/init.d` shouldn't be writing much, if anything, to standard output, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I tried with `mycmd("/etc/rc.common", 2, "/etc/init.d/sysntpd", "start");` and it works. I think this could be an answer. any other suggestion?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the service I start does not output anything

Comment: `mycmd("/etc/rc.common", 2, "/etc/init.d/sysntpd", "start");` is going to run `/etc/rc.common`, not `/etc/init.d/sysntpd`.

Comment: Then I definitely don't understand why you have the pipe, but it isn't going to do any harm either, I think.

Comment: Does the code work with any other (more trivial) script, for example just echoing the parameters passed in?

Answer (score 0):

Tried with

```
mycmd("/etc/rc.common", 2, "/etc/init.d/sysntpd", "start");
```

and it works.

Comment: It works but I do not have any explaination. Could any one explain why it works with that commands but it does not work with others?

Comment: Did you write `/etc/rc.common`, or is it system supplied?  Which Linux variant are you working with?

Comment: I asked which one and you said "it is one" (and implicitly, "I'm not going to tell you which one", though I've no idea why not).  There are apt to be differences in the administration of Linux — I don't know whether they're currently all the same in the `/etc/init.d` area, but historically, there were certainly differences between Linux variants at any given time.  Hence the information may be relevant.  And you didn't answer "Did you write the `/etc/rc.common` script or is it system-supplied?" question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler system supplied